# How can I adjust an image for the UIBarButtonItem in IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am facing a problem in placing an image for an UIBarButtonItem. This is the code I am uisng:

```
UIBarButtonItem *comoseButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"compose_new.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(composeNewMessage)];
```

But I am not getting the proper output: the button size is too big. How can I adjust the frame? (I'm developing for iOS 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always design my bar button items to be the right size. That seems the simplest way. I don't know if you've looked it up, but they should be "approximately 20x20" according to the [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Other than that, I suppose you could create a properly sized UIImageView with your image, add your own responder code or gesture recognizer, and then use `initWithCustomView:`.